# Differentiating exponential functions vs differentiating $x^x$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function

When differentiating an exponential function:
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x = a^x \ln(a),\, (a>0)$$

So why does differentiating $x^x$ result in $x^x(1 + \ln x)$ and not $x^x \ln x$?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $x^x=\exp(x\ln(x))$. Thus,

$$(x^x)'=(x\ln(x))'\exp(x\ln(x))=(x'\ln(x)+x\ln'(x))\cdot x^x=(\ln(x)+1)\cdot x^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

The rule you stated only works when the base is a $\textbf{fixed constant}$ like $2^x$ or $7^x$. In the expression $x^x$, the base is a variable. So your quoted rule does not apply here. To differentiate the function $f(x) = x^x$, other users have explained how to do so. So I will not include that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate with respect to both $x$’s. When you do to the top one, you get $x^x\ln x$ as you say. When you to do the bottom one, using the power rule, you get $x\cdot x^{x-1}=x^x$. Adding together, you get $x^x\ln x+x^x=x^x(1+\ln x)$.

The general fact here is that if $g(x,y)$ is differentiable in both variables, then $$\frac d{dx}g(x,x)=(\partial_xg)(x,x)+(\partial_yg)(x,x)$$ which you can straightforwardly prove from the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule that is rarely taught in calculus, which could be called the "generalized power rule" (it's available in my own book, "Calculus from the Ground Up", but I'm not familiar with another recent calculus books that contain it).  This is for differentiation of any expression of the form $q^z$ (note - I'm using $q^z$ instead of $u^v$ in order to better be able to see the difference in variables).  The solution is:

$$
d(z^q) = qz^{q - 1}\,dz + \ln(z)z^q\,dq
$$

Note that this is a combination of the power rule and the exponent rule added together.  So, for $x^x$, you just apply it for $x$ in both positions, which gives you:

$$
d(x^x) = x\,x^{x - 1}\,dx + \ln(x)x^x\,dx \\
d(x^x) = x^x\,dx + \ln(x)x^x\,dx \\
d(x^x) = x^x (1 + \ln(x))\,dx
$$

And, if you want a derivative instead of a differential, just divide both sides by $dx$, leaving you with:

$$
\frac{d(x^x)}{dx} = x^x (1 + \ln(x))
$$